# Access GPIO on beaglebone black using Java ME Embedded 8

Tags: java, embedded, debian, uart, beagleboneblack

I was wondering if it is possible to access the gpio, i2C, uart, etc. on the beaglebone black using Java ME embedded. I know that it is possible with the Java Native Access, but now there is an API Device I/O 1.0 wich is included in the Java ME Embedded 8. Has anyone any experience with this? I'm running debian on my beaglebone black.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you have any issues?

Comment: No, I didn't tried it yet. I'm unexperienced with this, and I was hoping to get an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaME Embedded 8.1 is only supported on RaspberryPi running on Linux for now (as well as on some other non linux embedded board).

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/embed-me/downloads/java-embedded-java-me-download-2162242.html

I have not tested using the RPi runtime with another linux board (Beagleboard for example), but I think it will definitively not work out of the box. Depending on how runtime is implemented, access to lowlevel IO such as GPIO or I2C can be platform-dependent.

Note the Device/IO API is getting integrated to OpenJDK implementation of Java platform (so this API is not specific to JavaME). But here too, this is limited to RaspberryPi.

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/dio/Main

Answer (score 1):

Try libbulldog: http://libbulldog.org/bulldog/

Or Kura: (you'll need a BeagleBone Black Rev C.)

https://www.eclipse.org/kura/index.php

http://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/beaglebone-quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find a example here :
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RaspberryPi_GPS/RaspberryPi_GPS.html#overview

It should work... But I'm trying to do this and I don't get any good result.

So good luck ^^

Comment: Thanks.
If you make any progress, please let me know :)

Comment: It's in progress... But not without difficulty. As you can see on this ticket :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859419/javame-raspberrypi-uart-to-rs485-connection-give-error-daapi-iso-1cannot-o

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem on accessing the GPIOs of a BeagleBoneBlack.

I have manage to solve this using the GPIO device tree overlay which the Linux Kernel exports to userspace. The nicest part about it: One single Jar which only requires Java SE 8.

My code is on GitHub: https://github.com/eitch/ch.eitchnet.beaglebone

To make it run on the Raspberry Pi two things need to be done:

- It needs Linux kernel 4.x (/sys/class/gpio)
- Write a new enum for the PINs (see https://github.com/eitch/ch.eitchnet.beaglebone/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/eitchnet/beaglebone/Pin.java)

These things should be not be a big problem i think.

Once this is done, accessing the GPIOs is as simple as this:

```
// Get Bridge:
GpioBridge gpioBridge = GpioBridge.getInstance();
Gpio pin8_07 = gpioBridge.getGpio(Pin.P8_07, Direction.IN);

// Read an input GPIOs value:
Signal currentSignal = gpioBridge.readValue(pin8_07);
System.out.println(pin8_07 + " currently has signal " + currentSignal);
Writing Output Pins

// Write an output GPIOs value:
Gpio pin8_08 = gpioBridge.getGpio(Pin.P8_08, Direction.OUT);
gpioBridge.writeValue(pin8_08, Signal.HIGH);
System.out.println("Set signal of " + pin8_08 + " to " + Signal.HIGH);
Observing Input Pins

// To be notified of changes to an input GPIO, register a GpioSignalListener:
gpioBridge.register(pin8_07, gpio -> System.out.println("Signal of "+pin8_07 + " has changed to " + gpio.getSignal()));
```